# Stylesheet broken in IE8

Tags: css, html, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I'm not sure what I did, because I'm sure this was fine before, but now IE8 is only loading a small portion of this site's stylesheet.  In every other browser it's fine.

```
http://50.57.131.195/adamekdev/
```

This is the stylesheet that's only partially loading:

```
http://50.57.131.195/adamekdev/wp-content/themes/skeleton_adamek/style.css?ver=1.6
```

I've run it through the validator and commented out any experimental css.

Any help would be appreciated.

It's a wordpress child theme of Skeleton.

Thanks

Comment: Which portions of the stylesheet aren't loading? That's usually a good place to start looking for a syntax/spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding different css for **IE**

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/ie-8.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/ie-6.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/ie-7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Turns out it is a problem with the media queries, but even after adding http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js it still isn't loading properly, so I've added a separate stylesheet for below IE9

Answer (score 0):

I think it was because I was using @media all and...  but I fixed with a separate stylesheet for ie8.